# How do i shrink the flexbox in tailwind?

Tags: css, flexbox, tailwind-css

[test picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8yKSR.png)
I have been stumbling a problem with flexbox, how can i shrink the flexbox?

This is the tailwind property that i added

```
<div class="flex justify-center bg-white rounded"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give the required `width` to the following div like using `w-40` class

Below is the implementation which solves the issue.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<div class='container m-10 p-5 bg-blue-800 mx-auto'>
  <div class="flex justify-center bg-white rounded w-40 mx-auto">How to Shrink ?</div>
</div>
```

I had wrapped them in container class and made bg-blue to make it look esthetic.

Comment: Currently i have two elements inside of it: 
<div className="flex justify-center bg-white rounded w-23 mx-auto">
         <p>Contact Number</p>
         <button className="px-4 py-3"><DropIcon /></button>
    </div>
how can i shrink it?
Thank you for the advice.

Comment: Just put them in `How to Shrink` div and accept answer